# SQL JOIN with a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

My query join is like this:

```
SELECT dbo.TARIF_COURANT.CODE_TARIF, 
dbo.TARIF_COURANT.NO_CLIENT,dbo.TARIF_COURANT.ZONE, dbo.TARIF_COURANT.UNITE, 
dbo.TARIF_COURANT.LIBELLE, dbo.TARIF_COURANT.TR_DEB, dbo.TARIF_COURANT.TR_FIN, 
dbo.TARIF_COURANT.MONTANT,dbo.T_TARIF_ZONE.LIBELLE AS ZONELIB, 
dbo.T_TARIF_ZONE.DEPARTEMENT, dbo.T_TARIF_ZONE.DELAI
FROM dbo.TARIF_COURANT LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_TARIF_ZONE ON 
dbo.TARIF_COURANT.ZONE = dbo.T_TARIF_ZONE.NO_ID
WHERE (dbo.TARIF_COURANT.TEMPO = 2) AND 
(dbo.TARIF_COURANT.ZONE IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 6))
ORDER BY dbo.TARIF_COURANT.TR_DEB
```

Now i add another table LS_CLIENT_DEPT, and i modify my join:

```
SELECT  dbo.TARIF_COURANT.CODE_TARIF, dbo.TARIF_COURANT.NO_CLIENT, 
dbo.TARIF_COURANT.ZONE, dbo.TARIF_COURANT.UNITE, dbo.TARIF_COURANT.LIBELLE, 
dbo.TARIF_COURANT.TR_DEB, dbo.TARIF_COURANT.TR_FIN, dbo.TARIF_COURANT.MONTANT, 
dbo.T_TARIF_ZONE.LIBELLE AS ZONELIB, dbo.LS_CLIENT_DEPT.DEPARTEMENT, 
dbo.T_TARIF_ZONE.DELAI
FROM dbo.TARIF_COURANT LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.T_TARIF_ZONE ON 
dbo.TARIF_COURANT.ZONE = dbo.T_TARIF_ZONE.NO_ID 
LEFT OUTER  JOIN dbo.LS_CLIENT_DEPT ON dbo.TARIF_COURANT.NO_CLIENT = 
dbo.LS_CLIENT_DEPT.CODE_CLIENT AND dbo.TARIF_COURANT.ZONE = 
dbo.LS_CLIENT_DEPT.ZONE
WHERE (dbo.TARIF_COURANT.TEMPO = 2) AND (dbo.TARIF_COURANT.ZONE IN (1, 2, 3, 
4, 6)) ORDER BY dbo.TARIF_COURANT.TR_DEB
```

The object is if the column DEPARTEMENT in table 'LS_CLIENT_DEPT' is 'NOT NULL' then use this column value else use the column DEPARTEMENT value from table 'T_TARIF_ZONE'

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
COALESCE(LS_CLIENT_DEPT.DEPARTEMENT, T_TARIF_ZONE.DEPARTEMENT)
```

So it will take Department from `LS_Client_Dept` if it isn't null, and if it is null, return Department  from `T_TARIF_ZONE` instead (this could be null too, however).

[MSDN Documentation on Coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).